# how to use facebook android sdk version 4.10

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

### facebook-android-sdk 4.10

1. I canot use facebook-android-sdk 4.10,i can not find the facebook sdk .jar file, beacuse i use adt-bundle-eclipse,not android-studio,so i need facebook sdk jar.and facebook sdk a complete sample for login in android app.
2. I have tried unzip the facebook android sdk .arr,find classes.jar, i add the classes.jar to my andorid project libs.but i donot know whether it's right.
3. Can anyone help? When I google it, I get no answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the facebook SDK integration by facebook site.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Steps:
1) You have to be a registered facebook developher. https://developers.facebook.com/
2) Have to be create App Id. https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android
3) have to add Add your development and release key hashes

Then for integrate login visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

In facebook developher support all documents are for android Studio. It is better to convert your project from eclipse to android studio.

You can show below link for SDK integration

1) https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk
2) http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-facebook-integration-tutorial
3) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837
4) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ (Eclipse)

If you use android Studio, you can use gradle link
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

Comment: thank you and i use the facebook-android-sdk:4.0 to solve my question.